# Plotting the origin

Tags: soft-question

I remember my high school teacher telling me that when I graph a function, I should always plot the point $(0, 1) $, $(1, 0) $ and the origin, $(0, 0) $. Always graphing the first two makes perfect sense, but plotting the origin seems unnecessary.  Isn't it obvious that the origin is where two axes intersect? So, I was wondering, was this requirement from my math teacher a sign of his ODD, or something that is useful down the "math learning road"?

Comment: In my opinion, your math teacher is pettifogging. One of my high school math teachers used to deduct a point for non-horizontal fraction bars. You will meet many such people as you make your way through life. Pity them, let them have their way, and move on.

Comment: I assume you mean OCD rather than ODD.  At any rate, I agree with MJD's assessment that labeling the origin isn't really necessary once you've labeled your axes and established the scale.  I can't think of any situation where doing so is particularly "useful".